# Converting System::String to Const Char *

Tags: c++, string, char, constants

I am using Visual C++ 2008's GUI creator to make a user interface. When a button is clicked, the following function is called. The content is supposed to create a file and name the file after the contents of the textbox "Textbox' with '.txt' at the end. However, that leads me to a conversion error. Here is the code:

`private: System::Void Button_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    ofstream myfile (Textbox->Text + ".txt");
    myfile.close();
}`

Here is the error:

> error C2664: 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ofstream(const char *,std::ios_base::openmode,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::String ^' to 'const char *'

How can I do a conversion to allow this to go through?

Comment: Man, I did this years back, and cant recall in what code I wrote it!

Answer (score 9):

It's simple!

As you're using managed C++, use the include  and operate like:

```
#include <msclr/marshal.h>

...

void someFunction(System::String^ oParameter)
{
   msclr::interop::marshal_context oMarshalContext;

   const char* pParameter = oMarshalContext.marshal_as<const char*>(oParameter);

   // the memory pointed to by pParameter will no longer be valid when oMarshalContext goes out of scope
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I would use marshalling:

```
//using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
const char* str = (const char*)(void*)
       Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(Textbox->Text);
// use str here for the ofstream filename
Marshal::FreeHGlobal(str);
```

But note that you then use just Ansi strings. If you need unicode support you can use the widechar STL class `wofstream` and `PtrToStringChars` (`#include <vcclr.h>`) to convert from `System::String`. In that case you do not need to free the pinned pointer.

Comment: Cool, that was the code I wrote! +1

Comment: +1 Exactly what I writing, except I prefer static_cast<const char*>(
Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(Textbox->Text).ToPointer())

Comment: Good point James, better using C++ casts like you suggest!

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlconv.h>
#include <vcclr.h>

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    String^ managedStr = gcnew String(L"Hello, Managed string!");
    //If you want to convert to wide string
    pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch = PtrToStringChars(managedStr);
    std::wstring nativeWstr(wch);
    //if you want to convert to std::string without manual resource cleaning
    std::string nativeStr(CW2A(nativeWstr.c_str()));
    std::cout<<nativeStr<<std::endl;
    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks jdehaan. I little modified the code to use it with my 'normal' System::String's.

```
void MarshalNetToStdString(System::String^ s, std::string& os)
{
    using System::IntPtr;
    using System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal;

    const char* chars = (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s)).ToPointer( );
    os = chars;
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void*)chars));
}
```

This is the way if you want to convert System:String -> std:string.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a CString and then add the extension to it.

There is a built-in CString constructor which will allow this conversion to happen

Example:

```
CString(Textbox->Text)
```

In your specific case:

```
private: System::Void Button_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) 
{
    ofstream myfile (CString(Textbox->Text) + ".txt"); 
    myfile.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Any clue why it's returning ''CString': identifier not found' when I have included string.h?

Comment: CString is part of the MFC Libraries - is the project using MFC (i'm guessing its not)? (Project Properties/Configuration Properties/General/Use of MFC)

Comment: If I select 'Use MFC in a static library' then it returns: 'Command line error D8016 : '/MT' and '/clr:pure' command-line options are incompatible' Sorry, I'm somewhat of a beginner, and this is irritating me.

Comment: Yea that Gem,  in order to use MFC you'll have to change the /CLR setting and remove pure (Project Properties/Configuration Properties/General/Common Language Runtime Support)  - this was not a problem in my case, if it is for your project you will not be able to MFC (as far as i know) - there is probably a similar wrapper somewhere that could be used without MFC but i don't know of it yet (rather than handling the marshaling directly as supplied by jdehaan - or you can write your own i guess).

Comment: This page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b4az623.aspx may be of use - its converting from CLR String^ to STL string, which won't require any MFC and it encapsulates the conversion and memory handling.

Answer (score 0):

There is an really excellent article in MSDN about String conversions here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631%28vs.80%29.aspx

There are many samples to convert String from and to different types.